# AJAX Replace Span String with External Date String

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Good morning,

I have [Livestamp.js](http://mattbradley.github.io/livestampjs/) on my website and an external .php file that parses a date string from the VATSIM data file.

The code for the PHP file is:

```
<?php
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

$logFile = './vendor/skymeyer/vatsimphp/app/logsusers.log';

$vatsim = new \Vatsimphp\VatsimData();
$vatsim->setConfig('cacheOnly', true);
$vatsim->setConfig('logFile', $logFile);

if ($vatsim->loadData()) {
    $info = $vatsim->getGeneralInfo()->toArray();
echo "{$info['update']}";
} else {
echo "Cannot load data";
 }

?>
```

This is my code for pulling the date string from the external file into my [website](https://vatsim.theobearman.com/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_update() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'update.php',
        data: {
            request: 'true'
        },
        success: function(reply) {
            $('.data-livestamp').html("" + reply + "");
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    get_update();
});
</script>
```

The Livestamp.js code for the HTML has to look something like this: `<span data-livestamp="1454063536"></span>`

How can I change the AJAX code to either replace the example date string with the data string from my PHP file or to insert the contents of the PHP file in between the quotation marks in the `<span data-livestamp="1454063536"></span>` line?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: @Adam and what should I put in the HTML?

Comment: what do you exactly have in your `reply` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked the answer out:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function get_update() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'update.php',
        data: {
            request: 'true'
        },
        success: function() {
            $('#update').livestamp(new Date());
        }
    });
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    get_update();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

simply you can do this !

```
    success: function(reply) {
        $("[data-livestamp]").data('livestamp', reply)
    }
```

Comment: a little explanation could go a long way and earn you more points!

Comment: What about the HTML?

Comment: @davejal you right but i think simple answer is better sometimes !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
success: function(reply) {
            $("[data-livestamp]").attr('data-livestamp', reply)
        }
```

Comment: and leave the HTML as it is?

Comment: I've implemented the changes with leaving the space between the quotation marks empty and nothing is appearing.